# Is Hour between an hour range?

Tags: android, date

The closest post I found on my question is [How to compare current time with time range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377278/how-to-compare-current-time-with-time-range) But this doesn't work for me because i need to know if the current time on the users device is between a time range

so i got the current time like this...

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss a");
    String horaString = dateFormat.format(hour);
    Log.i("ALO","HORAAAAAASSSSTRRRRIIIINNNNGGG---->"+horaString);

    first = horaString.charAt(11);
    Log.i("ALOP","Char at 11 ---->"+first);
    char second=horaString.charAt(12);
    Log.i("ALOP","Char at 12 ---->"+second);
    char third=horaString.charAt(13);
    char fourth=horaString.charAt(14);
    char fith=horaString.charAt(15);


    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(first);
    sb.append(second);
    sb.append(third);
    sb.append(fourth);
    sb.append(fith);

    String currentTime = sb.toString();
```

now what is need to do is

```
6:00>=currentTime<=8:30 //Can i still do the comparison with AM/PM?
```

So this is what I need to do if currentTime = 8:29  a method that lets me know is True with a boolean.

Comment: Exactly how is this different from the question you are linking to?

Comment: It is different because i need to know if the current time is >= or <= .

Comment: And you expect the device clock to be accurate enough to determine that? Anyway, thanks for the clarifying answer.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

```
    final LocalTime rangeBegin = LocalTime.of(6, 0);
    final LocalTime rangeEnd = LocalTime.of(8, 30);

    LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Bogota"));

    boolean inClosedRange = ! (currentTime.isBefore(rangeBegin) || currentTime.isAfter(rangeEnd));
```

If you prefer to trust the device time zone setting rather than a hard-coded (or configured) time zone, use `LocalTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())`.

Since `LocalTime` hasn’t got an `isBeforeOrEqual` method nor an `isEqualOrAfter`, I am putting the condition negatively: if the current time is neither strictly before nor strictly after the range, it must be within it. Some will prefer the longer but also more direct:

```
    boolean inClosedRange = currentTime.equals(rangeBegin)
            || (currentTime.isAfter(rangeBegin) && currentTime.isBefore(rangeEnd))
            || currentTime.equals(rangeEnd);
```

You will notice how much simpler it still is than your code using `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. I personally also find it clearer. I am using and recommending java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: thanks great responce one i check if it works i will check on your answer cool responce

Answer (score 0):

There are two useful command: [After](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after(java.util.Date)), [Before](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before(java.util.Date)).
Here is an example how you can use them:

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

```
Date fromTime = dateFormat.parse("6:00");
Date toTime = dateFormat.parse("8:30");
Date currentTime = dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(new Date()));

if(currentTime.after(fromTime) && currentTime.before(toTime)) {
    // To do
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitro for your quick responce. I have a question though does this before or after method will take when is = also , for example when is 8:30.

Comment: @FelipeFranco Nope. Add some case to check if currentTime equals to toTime variable.